# Multiple MobileFirst apps in one APK

Tags: version-control, ibm-mobilefirst

We are working with a team of multiple developers in a MobileFirst project. The issue is that we have only one APK for a multi-app development.

What is the best approach?

1. Work with one APK in development on a single MobileFirst app?
2. Work with multiple APKs on multiple MobileFirst apps, and then merge all the code into one MobileFirst app?

Is there any example of how to divide the code in a project like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best option will be to work on a single project, single app and move your project under some kind of version control (git, svn, cvs, rtc or any version control system). This will reduces headaches later when trying to manually merge code into a single app.

Since you are working on a single project in a team you may need to stub/mock some of the dependencies that other people are working on.

For more info on which files you should check into version control check [Integrating with source control systems](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_integrating_with_source_contro.html?lang=en) in IBM Knowledge Center